# Terminal not able to display UTF-8 correctly - ex.23 LPTHW

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner and I'm trying to learn some Python using the book **LPTHW** by Zed A. Shaw.
At the moment I'm at **ex.23** of the book, and it seems the goal is to show the reader how to decode and encode letters in different languages.
Here's the code I wrote:

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv

def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)

def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8") # Unicode Transformation-8-bit

main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Here's a screenshot of the output on the Terminal when I  run the code:
[Code output on CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEYkU.png)

That is not all the output of the code, it is too long to be able to take a screenshot, but you get the idea.
On some languages I get some kind of strange question marks, can someone explain me why and how can I fix that?
Again I'm a beginner so I apologize if I said some names wrong or didn't explain myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the font used by the terminal can't display some of the characters, so it displays a substitute instead.  You can try changing you terminal to use different fonts to see which work (generally fonts with "unicode" in their name).

Comment: You are getting question marks in boxes because Windows Console does not fully support Unicode. it supports UCS2, which was the predecessor of UTF16, and is is essentially UTF16 but without support for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (so, for example, no emojis). Run your program in IDLE, which (in Python 3.8 and above) does support all of Unicode. This will avoid your being confused by the shortcomings of `cmd`. And, before you ask,  Powershell isn't much better at this.

Comment: @BoarGules 
Thanks for your help! You have definitely cleared my mind as these are new topics for me. I will try with IDLE even if in the book the author says not to use it.

Comment: That advice about not using IDLE is probably stems from the author's dissatisfaction with earlier versions. I recommended PythonWin over IDLE from Python 1.5.2 until Python 3.5 but I wouldn't  give that advice now.

Comment: @BoarGules I'm on Python 3.6, should I stick with IDLE?

Comment: Python 3.6 is over 5 years old. IDLE 3.6 has similar shortcomings to Windows Console when it comes to displaying Unicode characters outside the BMP. That was fixed only in 3.8 (along with other stuff about encoding) and backported to later versions of 3.7. Unless there is a compelling reason to keep with 3.6, I would install 3.10 alongside it (no need to upgrade) and only use the older version when needed. For example I had 2.6  installed even though I was actually using 3.6 because I needed the old version for work as it was embedded in a package I supported.

Comment: @BoarGules 
I understand, I installed Python 3.6 because it is the version used in the book and recommended by the author. I thought using a different version might give me trouble understanding and learning the syntax that was used. Maybe I should just install the latest version (3.10) and switch between the two as you advised me.